# Is it possible to set a property with no setter using Moq?

Tags: c#, moq

Im doing some research. I want to use moq and pass it to an MVC controller so allow it to set some values in session. I have written some code to see if its possible to 'open up' a property with no setter. Just don't know if its possible...

The following code was my attempt at trying to set a property witn no setter!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Moq;

namespace TestMoq
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var mock = new Mock<TestClass>();

            mock.SetupProperty(f => f.VarWithNoSetter);

            mock.Object.VarWithNoSetter = "Set";

            Console.WriteLine(mock.Object.VarWithNoSetter);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    public class TestClass
    {
        private string _varWithNoSetter;
        public string VarWithNoSetter
        {
            get { return _varWithNoSetter; }
        }

        public TestClass()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Sure:

```
mock.SetupGet(f => f.VarWithNoSetter).Returns("Hi, Exitos!");
```

Answer (score 4):

For me it doesn't work with SetUpGet, without making the property virtual. However it works by using Mock.Of<>:

```
var mock = Mock.Of<TestClass>(m=>m.VarWithNoSetter == "the value");
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can but you have to make that property virtual at it will be possible as Moq will generate a proxy

```
public virtual string VarWithNoSetter
{
   get { return _varWithNoSetter; }
}
```

or you can use `.SetUpGet`